# Rethinkdb: Changefeed - > How to look at/return 2 fields?

Tags: python, field, rethinkdb

I have a table where each row has 10 different fields, but for a certain Changefeed I'm using I'm only interested in looking if there is a change in one of the fields, but return two of them.

For instance, if I have a table with the rows [id, name, age, height] I'd want to see all the changes made only in age (I don't care about the height changes) and I want the cursor to return both the fields Name and age.

I know that to look at one field I can do:

```
r.table('Customers').get_all(*list_of_customers*).get_field('age').changes.run()
```

but this wouldn't return the ID or the Name.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pluck`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/pluck/), which accepts several fields, instead of `get_field`.